# Can someone help me understand and solve this "Failed to install @parcel/transformer-image"? (JS)

Tags: node.js, module, parceljs

I've been trying and failing repeatedly to install this parcel module and because of it I can't show images. I'm new to both using JS and using parcel and english is not my native language, so please ask for some patience here.

The error that appears is

> Failed to install @parcel/transformer-image: npm failed to install modules: Unexpected token > in JSON at position 1

I've tried numerous solutions:

- I've tried to uninstall and reinstall only the parcel/transformer-image module
- I've already tried uninstalling and reinstalling the entire parcel
- I've already tried uninstalling and reinstalling node-js and npm
- I've already tried to install node through node manager nodist, but I ran into another error

At first, the build didn't work, but when I deactivated  and activated the parcel again, it worked, but without loading the images.
At this the moment the error doesn't appear anymore, but the image still doesn't load (and I inspected the element and saw that the link where the image should be loaded is correct).

After installing nodist and even after uninstalling it I'm having problems installing the parcel, but I managed it anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I solved it.  There were two issues I needed to resolve:

1. "npm install parcel" in any form/version did not work. After consulting Parcel's install guide they recommend installing parcel-bundler NOT parcel:

```
npm install parcel-bundler --save-dev
```

SOURCE: https://parceljs.org/getting_started.html

2. Once installed, I immediately ran into an error - Uncaught ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined - when doing the first async/await function.

To solve this I had to add the code below for "browserslist" to package.json

```
{
    "name": "my-app",
    ...
    "browserslist": [
        "last 1 Chrome versions"
    ],
    ...
}
```

SOURCE: https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/2128

package.json settings shown in the pic attached.

[image]

Comment: It did not work... a new error is showing:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined`

And I did not understand why `sass` and `@parcel/transformer-sass` are both installed in different versions. Also parcel is following the same

Comment: It did solve it!
As said by this [user](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/2128#issuecomment-547446319) the problem was because the `parcel-bundler` uses `babel`.
Edit: just realize you are studying the same course as I am :)

Comment: Glad you got it. FYI since then, I think they updated parcel. I did a fresh install based on the most recent how to on the parcel website and all of these problems went away. Good luck in the course!

Answer (score 0):

most recent that worked for me:

```
npm install --save-dev parcel
```

[found on the parcel website](https://parceljs.org/getting-started/webapp/)